# Is there a way to align the view plane of my camera parallel to the object surface in the scene?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration

I'm setting up two cameras in an orthogonal way so that each camera can see one of the adjacent surfaces of the cube put in the middle and the angle between the principle lines of the two cameras is 90 degrees. I'm thinking about pasting two chessboard patterns on each side of the cube being viewed to help the alignment. How should I proceed or are there any other options?

The layout is basically like this:
[image]

The angle between the principle lines need to be very close to 90 degrees, or at least I can quantify the error some how, so I abandoned physical approaches.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
The distance between the center of the cube and the view planes of the two cameras is 400 inches;
the focal length of the camera is 0.77 inches;
the horizontal view angle of the FOV(field of view) is 0.95 rad;
the aspect ratio of the view is 1280x720.

The cube works as a reference object just to setup the cameras. It could be either big or small while I assume a 1m x 1m x 1m cube would be reasonable.

The effect of thermal conditions can be ignored here.

The error I am aiming at is +-1 degree. It seems doing calibrations on the target side gives me less error compared with using something like bubble tube on the camera side.

I've been using pose estimation method with a chessboard (https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_pose/py_pose.html). But it stopped working or being no longer accurate when the chessboard surface's normal vector is aligned with the normal vector from the view plane of the camera.

Is there any other proper solutions to the problem explained above?

Comment: Seems you've tagged your question with c++ and python, which are you actually asking for? If you are asking for a particular software, those tags are irrelevant and should be replaced with a tag identifying the software you are asking about.

Comment: I'd suggest digging into chapter 11. here http://www-cs.ccny.cuny.edu/~wolberg/capstone/opencv/LearningOpenCV.pdf

Comment: You need to define your parameters a little more precisely. How close to 90deg? What is your acceptable error? What is the size of the cube? What is the field of view of the cameras.
Note that if your required accuracy gets close to a tenth of degree or less you definitely need to start worrying about the mechanical and thermal stability of the setup, and control that as well

Answer (score 0):

The pose estimation should be sufficient (why it is stop working in your case??).
or you may need an alternative calibration, scroll below!

first.
you define the intrinsic parameters of both camera.

second.
you place chessboards pattern which is a good option since you will get more accurate image points result by detecting the corners. you already know the geometry and distance of those pattern and you define top left corner of the chessboard as origin (0,0,0) like standard opencv (is it?).

third.
you use solvePnP to get the pose estimation (rotation and translation). You have to put (and be careful) initial rotation and translation into the solvePnP() as this will determine your whole result.

fourth.
you adjust your cameras position into desired 90 degrees. at this point, make sure your cube sides where you put your chessboard is perfectly 90 degrees too. you can have the combination of manual calibration and pose estimation from opencv.

alternatives: (light source callibration)

you can use interferometer concept from optical physics, replace your camera with light source and mark its place carefully. replace cube with prism lense and mark its place carefully.

you can borrow the interferrometer concept and set it in your own term.

once you get what you want, put the camera back and take it as your initial rotation and translation position of step 3 above.